# How to gracefully restart a HTTP API with timers

Tags: go, logic, dev-to-production

I have a HTTP api written in golang on the go-fiber framework that handles bookings.

```golang
type Booking struct {
  Active    bool      `bson:"active"`
  Created   time.Time `bson:"created"`
  StartDate time.Time `bson:"start_date"`
  EndDate   time.Time `bson:"end_date"`
}
```

When a booking is created, I want to be able to send the user a notification when that booking starts, etc. These notifications are important. I also want a timer to be set which'll automatically set the booking to inactive (`active: false`).

If this program were to crash, or I have to restart it due to updates, all those timers would be gone.

How should I implement a system which'll gracefully restart the API and persist those timers?

My idea:
When the program restarts, I can just query & iterate through all bookings where `active: true` and start those timers again. Seems obvious enough?

I'd like to know if there's any other practical solution or if there's  any "best practices"?

Comment: You might want to consider a system based on events ordered by time (like bookingStartEvent, bookingEndEvent, etc), and a separate process that waits until the next event. You'd need to reset that any time an event is created at the head of the list. If for some reason you miss events because of a crash, etc. you can reprocess them when system restarts.

Comment: @BurakSerdar So have the REST API as one program, and an event handler on another? Could you further elaborate on that in terms of relaying the data from process to process? I feel like this might be excessive, but I am open to hear new ideas. 

Also, I don't understand where timers are involved in any of this.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a new program. You can do it as a separate goroutine in the same program. My point is that having a timer for each event may not scale, and difficult to manage if program stops, or if there are multiple instances of the same program.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I see. I'm not sure how to incorporate this design. When `POST /bookings` is called, I would expect the bookingStart event to be emitted. But, when is the bookingEnd event emitted? That would require a timer...

Comment: You can use a timer. You have to recreate all the timers if system shuts down. You will need one timer for each booking. Depending on what you are building, this may or may not scale. You can do it with one timer that waits until the closest event. Once all the events that expired at a given time is processed, the timer waits until the next event.

Comment: You can also consider changing the boolean field to something like `ActiveBefore time.Time`. Then you might not need a Timer at all.